# Angular2 new component object on different url

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-components

I have `PageComponent` which data is renewed on different url (by using `PageService`). It uses same `PageComponent` object. I want that `PageComponent` would be new object on new url.

- **1st Q**: How to create new `PageComponent` on different url?
- **2nd Q**: Is it good approach if new Component is made on different
  url?

```js
const routes: Routes = [
    {path: ':uri', component: PageComponent}
];
```

Comment: Your question is really vague.

Comment: Redefined question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IF you are using angular 2 routing then there will be an index.html page and the component will be changed depending on the path in the URL.

For Ex.

```
RouterModule.forRoot([
  { path: 'heroes', component: HeroesComponent},
  { path: 'details', component: HeroesDetailComponent}
])
```

It will load HeroesComponent when URL will be `/heroes` at place of 
`<router-outlet>` in index.html page and when URL will be `/details` then it will load `HeroesDetailComponent` at the place of `<router-outlet>`.

For detail, you can read below URL

```
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt5.html
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same `PageComponent` for the page that is routed. if you need another routing on this page you can put `<router-outlet/>` to the page template and provide other components on it.

```typescript
const routes: Routes = [
    {path: ':uri1', component: Component1},
    {path: ':uri2', component: Component2},
    ...
];
```